# How do I switch from /etc/shadow back to /etc/passwd?

Tags: linux, authentication, shadow

I'm playing with a rather old, heavily customized Linux installation (based on Debian etch, running on a Netgear ReadyNAS device).

Recently I've switched from `/etc/passwd` to `/etc/shadow` via `pwconv`.

Now I'd like to switch back due to authentication problems with the Apache server, because `mod_auth_shadow` is not installed and I'm hesitant to install it.

As an additional complication: `pwunconv` does not exist either.

I have a backup, but it's old and I have been installing a lot of packages since it was taken. I also have the option of doing a factory reset, but that will mean I lose the RAID configuration which I do not want.

What steps would I need to take to go back to regular passwd-based password authentication rather than shadow passwords?

Comment: Have a look in /etc/pam and friends. Chances are there's a call to the shadow password authentication module there that might need to be replaced.

Comment: Are we to assume that you don't have a useful backup to restore from, or are you just wondering which files to restore?

Comment: @Michael I do have a backup, albeit an older one, made at the time before I started installing all kinds of libs and packages. There also is the option of factory-resetting the box, but that's scary because I would lose the RAID. I prefer poking the right files, but currently I lack the necessary understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pwconv` command automagically backups the `/etc/passwd` in a file called `/etc/passwd-`.

Try to restore this file and rename `/etc/shadow` to `/etc/shadow-`.

Comment: You mean `passwd` and `passwd-`? Yes, that file exists. But how do I configure the system to stop using `shadow`?

Comment: @Tomalak, remove or rename it.

Comment: Okay, sounds reasonable enough, I just wanted a confirmation. I'll try and report back.

Comment: I've renamed `/etc/shadow` to `/etc/shadow_` and `/etc/passwd-` to `/etc/passwd`. So far this had no ill-effects, I can still log in normally. (Apache still does not let me in though, apparently that's a disconnected problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going back manually you could try if you have the apache PAM authentication module available "libapache2-mod-auth-pam" as a distribution supported package.

I have no test boxes that old but the pam_unix module supports both shadow and regular passwd, so I would think that merging the encrypted passwords back into your `etc/passwd` file and renaming the /etc/shadow* files should be sufficient. You may need to add the option `broken_shadow` to pam configuration files in /etc/pam.d/* referencing the pam_unix module.

Comment: Yes, I've tried installing that module (`apt-get`), but for some reason it wouldn't install. I did not want to break apache by meddling with it unless I also had a way to back out. I'll try merging/renaming as soon as I understand what makes the system use `shadow` in the first place.

Comment: It's a single user system anyway, so having all stuff in `/etc/passwd` is not a real drawback. I'm also hesitant of changing stuff in `/etc/pam.d` for fear shutting myself out of the system. I have set up ssh with public key authentication, is there a chance that changing `pam_unix` options breaks this?

Comment: Changing pam settings typically doesn't break existing sessions...

Comment: Now that I know I can easily switch between shadow and passwd I can try to make authentication work in apache.